# JSON to HTML Table?

Tags: html, json, html-table

How can I generate html table form this url's json output?

http://megagrup.site/entegrasyon/hepsiburada.php

**Update**

I will find result like this;

```
<?php
$json=file_get_contents("url");
$data =  json_decode($json);

if (count($data->listings)) {
    // Open the table
    echo "<table>";

    // Cycle through the array
    foreach ($data->listings as $idx => $stand) {

        // Output a row
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$stand->abc."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$stand->def."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    // Close the table
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to output the properties of the $stand object. You need an additional loop to iterate over the properties.

```
<?php
$json=file_get_contents("http://megagrup.site/entegrasyon/hepsiburada.php");
$data =  json_decode($json);

if (count($data->listings)) {
    // Open the table
    echo "<table>\n";

    // Cycle through the array
    foreach ($data->listings as $idx => $stand) {

        // Output a row
        echo "  <tr>\n";

        // Output a cell for each property of the $stand object
        foreach ($stand as $key => $value) {
            echo "    <td>" . $value . "</td>\n";
        }

        echo "  </tr\n";
    }

    // Close the table
    echo "</table>\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will find result like this;

```
<?php
$json=file_get_contents("url");
$data =  json_decode($json);

if (count($data->listings)) {
    // Open the table
    echo "<table>";

    // Cycle through the array
    foreach ($data->listings as $idx => $stand) {

        // Output a row
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$stand->abc."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$stand->def."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    // Close the table
    echo "</table>";
}
```

?>

Comment: I edited your question to include this info. I suggest you delete this answer.